# Barcode Scanning using laser scanner in react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, barcode-scanner, ikscannerdeviceview

I have a scannnig device Unitech PA730 and want to read barcode text with its laser scanner and get the data in React native cli application, but I can't find any suitable package because every package is outdated or doesn't work and SDK is very hard to understand is there anyway to read the barcode text without so much hurdle?

I have tried almost every packages and even try to do this with events

Comment: did you tried ? 
https://github.com/philpettican/react-native-unitech-scanner

Comment: Yes I have tried but i doesn't work for me

Comment: Can you please give any working example through this library?

Comment: I just share you u reference. I dind't implement it.